# How to add link for another page in wordpress custom theme

Tags: wordpress

I have downloaded a template and now I want to set up links in the header. There are links like about us, contact us and service page.

I have tried links like this but clearly it is wrong.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav align-items-center">
     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="services.php">services</a>
     </li>


     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

When I tried to google it only results I have found is by adding menus in wordpress. Is there any other approach so that it can be completed on a coding level without using wordpress solution because when I tried to do same thing done [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FN5jhyspVXc) in the last part of video, I lost all my styles applied to the header menu. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since wordpress uses a routing system trying to go directly to about.php won't work. Try the following:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
```

Comment: It still remains same. I changed my code to href="/about-us" and there is a page named about-us.php in the same folder as header.php but it still is not directing to the desired page. Is there some settings that needs to be done inside wordpress?

Comment: Try going to the "Permalinks" section in the admin area and select "Post Name" from the options.